# Azure Azcopy - can I copy only the folders without files?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files, azcopy

I want to clone my existing azure file shares and just need the folders structure without copying the files.

Is there any way for me to use the Azure Azcopy to copy only the folders without files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Azcopy does not support only copy the folder structure.

As a workaround, you can use Azcopy to copy all folders/files, then in the `destination storage account`, use Azcopy to remove all the files, then only the folder structure will be kept.

The [remove command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) below will remove all the files, but leave the folder structure:

```
azcopy rm 'https://xx.file.core.windows.net/file_share_name?sas_token' --recursive --include-pattern='*.*'
```